# Printing content issue within SVG content

Tags: asp.net, html, svg, printing

I am working on rendering the Visio charts on browser. I managed to display them using SVG.

While printing the same Visio charts I am using window.print().

Requirement is to place a watermark on every page occupying by chart while printing.

Currently using some calculation on basis of view box height

I am inserting the SVG with image tags inside the parent SVG tag on certain heights which is working as a watermark.

But calculation breaks some time and watermark appear above the footer position or slide down to next page which results to some pages with no watermark or some with watermark appearing twice.

Any solution using CSS or any other way would be highly appreciated!

Please check code snapshots below for better understanding:

***SVG xml file code snippet***:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/" width="6.53953in" height="12.0677in" viewBox="0 0 470.846 868.874" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st11">

<g>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" onmouseover="mouse_out()" />
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="569" height="100px" width="100%">
            <image xlink:href="/css/images/Copyright.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="50px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
        </svg>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="780" height="100px" width="100%">
            <image xlink:href="/css/images/Copyright.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="50px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
        </svg>

</g></svg>
```

***C# code to calculate positions to place watermark***:

```
private void AddWatermark(XmlDocument doc, XmlNode prevNode, int width, int height)
        {
            //Assumed A4 Paper Usable Height 
            double pageA4Height = 1000;
            //Assumed First Page Usable Height because on first page added owner, title and some basic information
            double headerPageHeight = 842;
            //Assumed Total Print Pages
            int totalPages = 1;
            double VwBoxHeight = height;
            //Assusmed First Water Mark Position 
            double waterMarkPos = 780;
            //Calculating Total Pages
            if (headerPageHeight < VwBoxHeight)
            {
                VwBoxHeight = VwBoxHeight - headerPageHeight;
                if (VwBoxHeight > pageA4Height)
                    totalPages += (int)Math.Ceiling(VwBoxHeight / pageA4Height);
                else
                    totalPages = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                //Set WaterMark Position For Single Page
                waterMarkPos = height * 92 / 100;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
            {

                //Initialize Water Mark Element And Set The Attributes 
                XmlElement watermark = doc.CreateElement("svg");
                watermark.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
                watermark.SetAttribute("x", "0");
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    watermark.SetAttribute("y", waterMarkPos.ToString());
                }
                else if (i != totalPages)
                {
                    waterMarkPos += pageA4Height;
                    watermark.SetAttribute("y", waterMarkPos.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    watermark.SetAttribute("y", (height - 300).ToString());
                }
                watermark.SetAttribute("height", "100px");
                watermark.SetAttribute("width", "100%");

                //Initialize Water Mark Image Element
                XmlElement waterMarkImage = doc.CreateElement("image", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
                waterMarkImage.SetAttribute("href", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/css/images/Copyright.jpg"));
                waterMarkImage.SetAttribute("x", "0");
                waterMarkImage.SetAttribute("y", "0");
                waterMarkImage.SetAttribute("width", "100%");
                waterMarkImage.SetAttribute("height", "50px");
                watermark.AppendChild(waterMarkImage);

                //Insert Water Mark Element in XML Node
                prevNode.InsertBefore(watermark, prevNode.FirstChild);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add code as text and not as a raster.

Comment: Added code snippets in question.